# What's a good program for tracking submissions?

Tags: technique, software, tools, submitting-work

What's a good program or technique for tracking submissions? I need something that'll keep track of who I've submitted to, when, if they've replied, and preferably tell me how long it's been out. Any suggestions? Preferably something that I don't need an internet connection to use. (IE, not a website.)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried a plain ol' spreadsheet?

Comment: I find an ordinary spreadsheet to be perfectly adequate.  I have one row per submission, with columns for the story title, the periodical title, date submitted, expected response time (if they list it), the response date, and the response (accept, reject, rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

I like Duotrope's online submission tracker: http://duotrope.com/

As a bonus, they also have a large, searchable database of markets, categorized in a variety of ways.

Or maybe they're a market database, and the tracker is a bonus. Either way, I like 'em.

Alas, it's an online service.

Answer (score 0):

I use a database that I built using Filemaker Pro. It's far from perfect, but I'd like to share [my notes about submission tracking](http://wp.me/p1rZqf-dA) in case they help you to decide how you would like to track your submission.

p.s. this same question is being asked in a few places on here:

[What's a good program for tracking submissions?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/whats-a-good-program-for-tracking-submissions)

[How do you track submissions to publishers/markets?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/433/how-do-you-track-submissions-to-publishers-markets)